# Reference a computed property in a jest unit test

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, ts-jest, vue-test-utils

I'm writing a jest unit test for my Vuejs 2 (Vuetify) component. Setup is pretty simple.

Inside the component I have a prop, which is an object with nested fields:

`props: ['testObject']`

And I have a computed property that returns a field from that prop:

```
computed: {
    myField() {
      return this.testObject.testField;
    }
}
```

And I write a Jest test:

```
wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
            mocks: {
                propsData: {
                    testObject: { testField: 'My Test Value' }
                }
            },
        });

it("should return a test field", () => {
    const field = wrapper.vm.$options.computed.myField();
    expect(field).toBe('My Test Value');
});
```

When I run the test I get the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'testField' of undefined
```

So it calls computed propperty, but testObject is undefined.

Any idea what's going on?

@vue/test-utils: 1.3.0
@vue/vue2-jest: 28.0.1
@types/jest: 28.1.3
jest: 28.1.1

Answer (score 4):

Your code failing because the `this` inside the computed function referencing `$options`. You need to access computed as a `vm`'s attribute, not the `$option`. Just do this.

```
expect(wrapper.vm.myField).toBe('My Test Value');
```

But there is one more problem here. Actually you don't need to test the `computed` value. Because if you accidentally remove this computed value rendering from template, this tests will still be passed. Instead, test what this string is rendered in html.

```
expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('My Test Value');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to mount your component this way:

```
wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
        propsData: {
            testObject: { testField: 'My Test Value' }
        }
    });
```

Check [this documentation](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#propsdata) for more informations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, no unfortunately it shows the same error..

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I worked it out by doing this:

```
it("should return a test field", async () => {
   wrapper.vm.$options.computed.testObject.call({ testField: 'My Test Value' });
   ...
});
```

Hope that will help for those who experience the same issue.